# Rendering Teapot using GLSL ES (OpenGL ES 2.0) on Android

Tags: android, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, augmented-reality

I am trying to demonstrate an Augmented Reality tracking solution on Android Device. Previously when I was working on PC, I use GLUT to render a teapot for demo. However when I switched to the phone, where I use OpenGL ES 2.0 for rendering (GLSL ES), I could not figure out an easy way to draw a teapot model. 
Appreciate any suggestions or any resources that could help me in this issues.

Comment: Does it have to be a teapot? What about 1000 random triangles? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could first try copying the environment e.g. from Android Live Wallpaper demos:
e.g. 
https://github.com/ghisguth/blurred-lines-live

Then the next issue would be to feed the geometry of your teapot to the vertex buffer instead of the random lines; next steps would be to use draw triangle instead of lines and to copy somewhere a decent vertex shader that does perspective transform and then getting somewhere a texture fragment shader and initialize (somehow) the texture (if not procedural...).

Answer (score -1):

GLUT is a really old library that is used to handle different OpenGL environments and context definitions in just 1 single library.

After GLUT there was FreeGLUT, which is the most popular library for this today but it's not really standard, it's more like a free port and evolution of the original GLUT rather than something that can get some kind of support from the OEM.

Modern OpenGL ES devices requires EGL, EGL is mandatory under Android, you need to use EGL in a way or another.

Comment: -1 The question was totally **not** about what to use for context and UI management and the whereabouts of GLUT, but about how to render a teapot if GLUT is not available. So your answer doesn't contain any useful information regarding the actual question (however strange that may be in the first place).